# vsFTP - GnuTLS error -15 in gnutls_record_recv: An unexpected TLS packet was received

Tags: ssl, ftp, ftps, ftp-server, gnutls

On the same server I have more then 20 domains.
vsftpd manage FTP user. All works fine except with 1 user. Just one...

GnuTLS error -15 in gnutls_record_recv: An unexpected TLS packet was received

Why?  What's wrong?!

```
Tue May  5 18:31:49 2020 [pid 20607] CONNECT: Client "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"
Tue May  5 18:31:49 2020 [pid 20607] FTP response: Client "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx", "220 (vsFTPd 3.0.3)"
Tue May  5 18:31:49 2020 [pid 20607] FTP command: Client "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx", "AUTH TLS"
Tue May  5 18:31:49 2020 [pid 20607] FTP response: Client "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx", "234 Proceed with negotiation."
Tue May  5 18:31:49 2020 [pid 20607] FTP command: Client "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx", "USER myuser"
Tue May  5 18:31:49 2020 [pid 20607] [altshock2_org] FTP response: Client "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx", "331 Please specify the password."
Tue May  5 18:31:49 2020 [pid 20607] [altshock2_org] FTP command: Client "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx", "PASS <password>"
Tue May  5 18:31:49 2020 [pid 20606] [altshock2_org] OK LOGIN: Client "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"
```

Comment: This is [not a programming question](//stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Opsss, You're right!
Sorry, sorry, sorry.

It's possibile to delete all?

Comment: Yes, you can delete your posts. And if you wish, you can re-post them on [su].

Answer (score 1):

OOOOOK. I'm so stupid. I suspected it was a permission problem...

THe user had the wrong path of home in /etc/passwd.

Now all works fine!